# How can I disable a cpu fan on a Dell laptop on Turnkey Linux?

Tags: configuration, laptop, file-server, fan

Just to preface this, I know this is a stupid idea and I could risk destroying my CPU. I'm willing to risk that because I have a reasonable setup that can replace the functionality of the fan.

I have an old laptop with a broken fan that makes a lot of sound, and I'm using it as a server because it's got decent hardware and a lot of storage. I've got a tabletop fan pointed directly at it, keeping it cool. What can I do to disable the laptop's fan? I've got i8kutils installed on it.

Comment: The fan can probably be replaced.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen if I install any fan other than the one that came in the laptop from the factory, the BIOS complains that there is a non-functioning fan.

Comment: Then you may need a fan identical to the one you have (vendor specific wiring springs to mind). Dell or ebay?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out one way to do it.

Change these lines in /etc/i8kmon.conf

```
# Temperature thresholds: {fan_speeds low_ac high_ac low_batt high_batt}
set config(0)   {{-1 0}  -1  40  -1  40}
set config(1)   {{-1 1}  30  60  30  60}
set config(2)   {{-1 2}  53  128  53  128}
```

to

```
# Temperature thresholds: {fan_speeds low_ac high_ac low_batt high_batt}
set config(0)   {{-1 0}  -1  40  -1  40}
set config(1)   {{-1 0}  30  60  30  60}
set config(2)   {{-1 0}  53  128  53  128}
```